# Mailboxer gem active record error on the conversations page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, mailboxer

I'm trying to setup the mailboxer gem. It is mostly setup but I get the following error when I send a message and it tries to display the conversations page

```
Couldn't find Mailboxer::Conversation with 'id'=2 [WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = 'Mailboxer::Message' AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = ? AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = ?]
```

it is highlighting this line of coding in conversations controller as the error point

```
 def get_conversation
    @conversation ||= @mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
 end
```

here is the conversations controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user
  before_action :get_mailbox
  before_action :get_conversation, except: [:index]
  before_action :get_box, only: [:index]
  before_action :get_conversation, except: [:index, :empty_trash]

 def index
    @user = current_user
  if @box.eql? "inbox"
    @conversations = @mailbox.inbox
  elsif @box.eql? "sent"
    @conversations = @mailbox.sentbox
  else
    @conversations = @mailbox.trash
  end

  @conversations = @conversations.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end

  def show
    @user = current_user
  end

  def reply
  @user = current_user
  current_user.reply_to_conversation(@conversation, params[:body])
  flash[:success] = 'Reply sent'
  redirect_to user_conversation_path
end


def destroy
  @user = current_user
  @conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
  flash[:success] = 'The conversation was moved to trash.'
  redirect_to user_conversations_path
end

def restore
  @user = current_user
  @conversation.untrash(current_user)
  flash[:success] = 'The conversation was restored.'
  redirect_to user_conversations_path
end


def empty_trash
  @user = current_user
  @mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|
    conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(deleted: true)
  end
  flash[:success] = 'Your trash was cleaned!'
  redirect_to user_conversations_path
end

def mark_as_read
  @user = current_user
  @conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  flash[:success] = 'The conversation was marked as read.'
  redirect_to user_conversations_path
end

  private

  def get_box
  if params[:box].blank? or !["inbox","sent","trash"].include?(params[:box])
    params[:box] = 'inbox'
  end
  @box = params[:box]
end

  def get_mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

    def authenticate_user
    unless ((current_user.id = params[:user_id]) unless current_user.nil?)
        #if logged in go to their messages page else go to login path
      flash[:error] = 'Looks like your not supposed to be there'
      redirect_to login_path

    end
  end


  def get_conversation
    @conversation ||= @mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
 end

end
```

I mostly followed [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/messaging-rails-mailboxer/) in setting the mailboxer gem up

I'm not sure why I'm getting the error or what I can do to fix it.

**update**

New error of

```
app/views/conversations/show.html.erb where line #19 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"reply", :controller=>"conversations", :id=>nil, :user_id=>"example-user"} missing required keys: [:id]


Parameters:

{"user_id"=>"example-user",
 "id"=>"4"}
```

conversations/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Your Conversations") %>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><%= @conversation.subject %></div>

  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="messages">
      <% @conversation.receipts_for(current_user).each do |receipt| %>
        <% message = receipt.message %>

         <%= message.sender.username %>
          says at <%= message.created_at.strftime("%-d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S") %>
        <%= message.body %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%= form_tag reply_user_conversation_path(@user, @conversation), method: :post do %> <!-- line 19 -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= text_area_tag 'body', nil, cols: 3, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Type something...', required: true %>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error(`Couldn't find Mailboxer::Conversation with 'id'=2`) you get because the `id = 2` of `conversions` does not exists.

so you can modify your error method something like below

```
def get_conversation
    @conversation = @mailbox.conversions.new || @mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Comment: Seems to work, I have another error now this one is a no route error because it thinks its `missing required keys: [:id]` and below that it has the parameters `{"user_id"=>"example-user",
 "id"=>"4"}` so I'm not sure how it thinks its missing when it is in the params

Comment: this is a route error please check `reply_user_conversation_path(@user, @conversation)` it might be `reply_user_conversations_path` without any params and `_conversions_path` not `conversion_path`

Comment: `form_tag reply_user_conversations_path, method: :post do` might be look like this

Comment: unfortunately not, `reply_user_conversation_path POST /users/:user_id/conversations/:id/reply(.:format) conversations#reply`

Comment: `reply_user_conversation_path` did you use it without @user and @conversion

Comment: The page loads but I cant send a reply message `undefined method `recipients' for nil:NilClass` on this line in the conversations controller `  current_user.reply_to_conversation(@conversation, params[:body])`

Comment: now it is another **new ** error please update reply_to_conversation method of user model

Comment: The method doesn't exist in the user model or anywhere else that I can find. I might have to look back on the tutorial I followed for it

Comment: can you please create a seperate question for it .. and if you think I have resolved your first query then can you please accept my post thanks you mate

Comment: Not sure if your answer fixed it or not. Once its working then I'll know and give you the answer if it fixed it. going to sleep now. I'll post another question tomorrow for the new problem

Comment: Hi mate your first problem was `Couldn't find Mailboxer::Conversation with 'id'=2 ` and it is solved as now it is getting an error on a different method..No problem accept not accept is your choice but for a other user who will get error can use the answer

Comment: Posted the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36296864/mailboxer-gem-undefined-method-recipients-for-nilnilclass incase your interested.